# Webkit Browser ; wont navigate to any website other than google

Tags: vb.net, webkit

I am trying to make a simple browser using Vb.net and WebKit 0.5 Cario build, and have reached a dead end.

Problem : Browser doesn't navigate to any other websites other than google.

I want to make a browser with added functionality to pull information from HTML5 websites.
thats the reason i am using Webkit.

Can anyone tell me how to go about doing this.

Thanks
Dinesh Salunke

Comment: What happens when you try and navigate to any other page? What error message do you get? What does your current code look like

Comment: I have solved that issue using OpenWebkitSharp, but now rammed in another issue, Does OpenWebkitsharp play HTML5 Wbm format videos ?? becuase that is my final goal.